# Acessar item variável no JSON utilizando Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou acessando uma API usando Node.js, que me retorna o JSON a seguir.

Preciso acessar campo `price`, porém o item `PETR4:` varia de acordo com o `symbol` informado.

Consigo acessar até `response.body.results`.

Como posso acessar o próximo item (que nesse exemplo é `PETR4`)?

```js
{
  by: 'symbol',
  valid_key: true,
  results: {
    PETR4: {
      symbol: 'PETR4',
      name: 'Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras',
      region: 'Brazil/Sao Paolo',
      currency: 'BRL',
      market_time: [Object],
      market_cap: 255916,
      price: 19.31,
      change_percent: -1.63,
      updated_at: '2020-09-29 20:47:36'
    }
  },
  execution_time: 0.01,
  from_cache: false
}
```

Comment: As vezes vem o campo `PETR4` e as vezes não, é isso?

Comment: O que pode vir além de `PETR4`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `Object.values()` para obter os valores de um objeto:

```js
    const resposta = {
      by: 'symbol',
      valid_key: true,
      results: {
        PETR4: {
          symbol: 'PETR4',
          name: 'Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras',
          region: 'Brazil/Sao Paolo',
          currency: 'BRL',
          market_time: [Object],
          market_cap: 255916,
          price: 19.31,
          change_percent: -1.63,
          updated_at: '2020-09-29 20:47:36'
        }
      },
      execution_time: 0.01,
      from_cache: false
    };

    const { price } = Object.values(resposta.results)[0];

    console.log(price);
```

> [**`Object.values()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
>
> O método `Object.values()` retorna um `array` com os valores das propriedades de um dado objeto, na mesma ordem provida pelo [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) laço (sendo a diferença que o laço `for-in` também enumera as propriedades na cadeia `prototype`).

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente não é a melhor forma de acessar tal propriedade (inclusive vou acompanhar o post para aprender), mas você pode utilizar um `for in` para iterar sobre a propriedade `PETR4` ou qualquer outra que vier dentro do `results`.

Exemplo:

```js
const json = {
  by: 'symbol',
  valid_key: true,
  results: {
    PETR4: {
      symbol: 'PETR4',
      name: 'Petróleo Brasileiro S.A. - Petrobras',
      region: 'Brazil/Sao Paolo',
      currency: 'BRL',
      market_time: [Object],
      market_cap: 255916,
      price: 19.31,
      change_percent: -1.63,
      updated_at: '2020-09-29 20:47:36'
    }
  },
  execution_time: 0.01,
  from_cache: false
}

const ativo = json.results
let objName,
    objProperties

for (let i in ativo) {
  objName = i // pega valor da propriedade PETR4
  objProperties = ativo[i] // pega o objeto interno da PETR4
}

console.log(objName) // 'PETR4'
console.log(objProperties) // imprime o objeto interno da PETR4
console.log(objProperties.price) // imprime a propriedade que você precisa
```